# Is there any possible to get the memory entry point of function?

Tags: c, windows, portable-executable

I created a child process from within my process with `CreateProcess()` and suspend the child process. I can get the main entry point in the memory of child process, but how should I get function entry point of child process?

This is how I get the main entry point of child process

```
DWORD FindEntryPointAddress( TCHAR *exeFile )
{
  BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION bhfi;
  HANDLE hMapping;
  char *lpBase;

  HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(exeFile, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

  if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    ;

  if (!GetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, &bhfi))
    ;

  hMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, bhfi.nFileSizeHigh, bhfi.nFileSizeLow, NULL);

  if (!hMapping)
    ;

  lpBase = (char *)MapViewOfFile(hMapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, bhfi.nFileSizeLow);

  if (!lpBase)
    ;

  PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpBase;

  if (dosHeader->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    ;

  PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 ntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)(lpBase + dosHeader->e_lfanew);

  if (ntHeader->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    ;

  DWORD pEntryPoint = ntHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase + ntHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;

  UnmapViewOfFile((LPCVOID)lpBase);

  CloseHandle(hMapping);

  CloseHandle(hFile);

  printf( "test.exe entry point: %p\n", pEntryPoint );

  return pEntryPoint;
} // FindEntryPointAddress()
```

And how should I get the function `foo()` entry point of child process?

child process like this

```
void foo()
{
  char str[10];
  strcpy( str, "buffer\n" );
} // foo()

int main()
{
  foo();
  return 0;
} // main()
```

Comment: If that's *exactly* the contents child process, the foo function won't have an entry point in the EXE - the compiler will inline it.

Answer (score 1):

May one ask - what for? If you want to run the child process, `CreateProcess()` does that for you. Running the process from an arbitrary function makes zero sense; since the RTL won't be initialized, the process is quite likely to crash.

If you want to call a function for/from the creator process, that's what LoadLibrary()/GetProcAddress() are for. `CreateProcess()` is something completely different.

If you want to debug in terms of individual functions, parsing the MAP file and/or the debug symbols is the way. If the function happens to be global and exported, parsing the PE export table might help.

Also, in modern compilers, the compile-time function may not have one definite entry point in the EXE file. Inlining and all that.

Comment: My purpose is if I don't have the child process source code and  I just get a .exe file, can I get the function entry point of child process.

Comment: Once you get that entry point (an address), what are you going to do with it? If you don't have the sources, how do you know even about the function's existence?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on something similar a long time ago and don't remember exactly so this might be off. But I believe you can get the function address from [SymFromName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681325%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) if there is enough symbol information. Or if it's exported, just get the address directly via [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

To patch the entry point, you can either do a static patch on the entry point through the PE header, or suspend the process once you run it and change EIP through [SetThreadContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: My purpose is if I don't have the child process source code, can I get the function entry point of child process.

Comment: You don't need the source code. There are symbol tables embedded in executables that provide a limited amount of information. If it doesn't even have that symbol information, then you are going to have to determine the target function's address through other heuristics.

Answer (score 0):

use EXPORTS in the .DEF file of your child process program,
then your program can search the IAT table to find the address.

You can also search the code to find those instructions that sets the frame pointer ,
then find a possible entry point . 
But you can not totally trust that address.